# Create a df from a dataframe using forloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
df
    date        chosen_f     price      rent         yield         profit
0 2015-06-08    banana      131.36     165.2      167.279999    165.020004  
1 2015-06-08    apple      231.36      163.2      165.279999    162.020004
```

```
metrics= ["price",  "rent", "yield", "profit"]
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'pair']
```

Expected Output is the below code written as a forloop, so that the dataframes created using the list "metrics" is generalisable:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    df1 = df[(df['chosen_f'] == fruit)]
    price = df1.loc[:, ['price', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('W').last()
    rent = df1.loc[:, ['rent', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('W').last()
    yield = df1.loc[:, ['yield', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('W').last()
    profit = df1.loc[:, ['profit', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna(how='all').resample('W').last()
```

Comment: your expected output seems to be not a series

Comment: Sorry yes ammended the code.

Comment: I have the feeling that using groupby would do all at once, `df1.set_index('date').groupby('chosen_f')[metrics].resample('W').last()`? Then you just need to select the chosen_f to create a new df for each one and store them as you want (that is not clearly explicated here)

Comment: i dont understand what you want, you want one dataframe with prices for choosen fuits?

Comment: Could you please add the expected output to the question? Without it, it's difficult to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I've updated the question.